# How to combine different columns into one table in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've collected some sensor-values for the Cloud(csv file) and noticed a problem which I think I can go around by combining different columns into one table. I have the following table:

```
Sensor1x, Sensor1y, Sensor1z, Sensor2x, Sensor2y, Sensor2z

12.1,       0.1,       0.2,        2.2,       3.3,       2.2

NaN,       NaN,        NaN,        NaN,        NaN,      4.5,

etc.
```

When I try to remove the NaN values from let's say the Sensor1 columns, for some reason, all values in Sensor 2 columns are set to 0, while all NaN values are removed from Sensor1 columns (so at least the NaN part worked for the specific columns). Another strange thing is that I only chose to remove NaN values from one column (Sensor1x for example), but they are removed in all x, y and z columns.

So, since this results in the first 3 columns being filled and the last 3 being null, I figured I could save the removed Nan Columns in 1 variable, and do the same for my Sensor2 columns, which would give the following two variables:

First Variable:

```
Sensor1x, Sensor1y, Sensor1z, Sensor2x, Sensor2y, Sensor2z

12.1,       0.1,       0.2,        0,       0,       0,

etc.
```

Second variable:

```
Sensor1x, Sensor1y, Sensor1z, Sensor2x, Sensor2y, Sensor2z

0,          0,         0,          2.2,       3.3,       2.2,

etc.
```

How would I combine these two variables so I get the full table?

Simple code I'm currently using in Jupyter Notebook:

```
SDO = pd.read_csv('SensorOutputData202021.csv')
SDO = SDO[SDO['Ax'].notna()]
SDO
```

The simple 3 lines I'm using to print the dataframe and remove the na values. And also the lines of code that for some reason nullifies the values from the rest of my three columns.

Image of my current sensor table:

[image]

Here is what happends when I use notna function on Ax:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code you are using and which is not working properly?

Comment: I included the three lines of code I'm using for getting the results above.

Comment: Not sure what you think `SDO[SDO['Sensor1x'].notna()]` will do. Are you trying to remove NaNs from Sensor1x?

Comment: Can you provide a sample set of data from `'SensorOutputData202021.csv'` and also provide us with your expected output.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove all NaN values from Sensor1x table. But instead it removes the NaN from Sensor1x, Sensor1y, Sensor1z values and nullifies Sensor2x, Sensor2y, and Sensor2z column for some reason.

Comment: When you say "remove" do you mean "replace"?

Comment: No, I really want all NaN values removed completely from my tables, so that I only have the non-NaN values left for each specific column. This is because the NaN values are to many, and therefore affect my plotted graphs and ML training algorithms in a bad way.

Comment: But if you have let's say a row 'Nan, Nan, Nan, value', do you want to delete the whole row?

Comment: I included an image of my data table. So I don't want to delete the whole row, just the NaN values from that specific columns, throughout the entire column. Also included picture of what happends when I remove Ax and how it affects Ay, and Az as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are using the [`notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) method which returns the mask of your column ('Ax'): Trues at values and Falses at NaNs. So then you can call:

```
SDO = SDO[SDO['Ax'].notna()]
```

You are removing each row where  `Ax is None`.

You cannot "just delete" Nones from the table as you should keep its structure.

I suggest you to look for the following methods in addition to `notna()`:

- [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) - replaces target value by another value;
- [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) - remove rows or columns with missing values;
- [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) - filling missing values using specific logic;

Also you can read this part of the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

So, depending on what you are going to do with your data you should or remove rows with NaN data completely or replace these NaNs with something that you can treat in your code in a meaningful way.

Comment: But if I dropna or use notna so I get the same table as I did in my image above. Save this as a specific variable, and do the same with the other 2 sensors (i.e. use notna on Gx and Mx each in the own dataframe variable). Then combine these into a single table?

Comment: If different rows can correspond to one 'entry' (so you kinda want to connect first appeared values for the 1st sensor with the first appeared values for the 2nd sensor and so on) then I think you can try `fillna` to fill NaN values and after remove duplicates with `drop_duplicates`